# How can I return nil if a key does not exist in OpenStruct?

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror

I have a hash that passed to `OpenStruct` in order to make it word with a `.`. This works perfectly. But when ever I try to access a key that does not exist `undefined method <unknown key> for #<Hash:0x7f24ea884210> (NoMethodError)` is raised. How can I make it return `nil`?

If I try the same thing with the original hash I get `nil` but not with `OpenStruct`!!

The snippet from the program:

```
TXT_HASH = load_data("test.txt")
pp TXT_HASH[:ftp][:lastname]  ## print nil as lastname does not exist

TXT = OpenStruct.new(TXT_HASH)
pp TXT.ftp.lastname  ## raises NoMethodError ## Can it return nil?
```

Comment: Can you show what you have so far?

Comment: @squiguy I added a small snippet. See if its ok

Comment: *How can I make it return nil?* By catching the error in your code and returning nil.  OpenStruct isn't going to return nil, no matter how badly you want it to. *If I try the same thing with the original hash I get nil but not with OpenStruct!!*  Is it your understanding that OpenStruct is a Hash?  Because it's not.  Just because a class has an instance variable which is a Hash does not mean the class is a Hash.

Comment: Ok, I get your point but if I send `TXT` to some other program. I will have catch this error when ever I try to access values in it!!? I want to avoid that. Is there a way to override the getter function of OpenStruct??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenStruct is not recursive. In this case `TXT.ftp` returns a Hash, not an OpenStruct, so `#lastname` is not defined.

If you want, there is a library called [recursive-open-struct](https://github.com/aetherknight/recursive-open-struct). Use it like this:

```
require 'recursive-open-struct'

TXT = RecursiveOpenStruct.new(TXT_HASH)
pp TXT.ftp.lastname #=> nil
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by `@Shel` would however be the best, simple and clean.

> **Note:**
>   If you do not want to require unnecessary library then there is another workaround to implement.
>   Yes OpenStruct is not recursive yet we can create our own recursive method to do so.

```
# This method is kind of factory to create OpenStruct instances
def get_recursive_ostruct(object)
  if object.is_a?(Hash) 
    object = object.clone
    object.each do |key, value|
      object[key] = get_recursive_ostruct(value)
    end
    OpenStruct.new(object)
  else
    object
  end
end
```

and to use this method

```
require 'ostruct'

hash = {first: 'this is first', second: {first: 'first of second', second: 'second of second'}}

obj = get_recursive_ostruct(hash)
#=>  #<OpenStruct first="this is first", second=#<OpenStruct first="first of second", second="second of second">> 

obj.second.second
#=> "second of second" 

obj.second.third
#=> nil
```

Moreover, if you want object not to return exception then there is a few workarounds as well.

```
TXT.ftp.lastname  ## raises NoMethodError 
TXT.ftp.try(:lastname)  ## returns nil if `lastname` is not available

TXT.try(:ftp).try(:lastname)  ## returns nil even if `ftp` is not available
```

> **Note:**
>   As far as I know, `try` method is only available inside `Rails` app not in `IRB` or `ruby` apps.
>
> I would use: `rescue` method
>   **Caution:** this method catches exceptions and responds accordingly; Don't use this if you need to respond to exceptions differently. I hope you understand

```
TXT.ftp.lastname rescue nil # respond with default value i.e. nil
TXT.ftp.lastname rescue '' # respond with default value i.e. ''
```

Comment: Right on. Making a method to recursively make hashes `OpenStructs` is what I would've done too. Doesn't require any modification to `OpenStruct`, external libraries, or messy rescuing.

Comment: @wspurgin Now some things about `OpenStruct` make sense to me. Does it have a `getitem` functions that I can override? Suppose if I print `TXT` it shows a big `openstruct` object but I want to display it as a hash!! Is it even possible?

Comment: @AnimeshPandey For your first question, yes and no. It implements the `[]` operator, but for your purposes, you don't want to mess with that. [Reading the source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_3/lib/ostruct.rb) might seem scary, but you can learn a lot from it. To answer your second question, if by "display it" you mean the output inside `irb` or the console, then yes you can change how it is output by modifying the `inspect` function. [This is how they currently do it in 2.2.3](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_3/lib/ostruct.rb#L234-L255)

Comment: @AnimeshPandey But I want to add this clarification, Why do you care how it looks? It's like saying "I have this dog, that I want to behave like a chicken, but still look like a dog". If you want it to *look* like a dog, than make it a dog. If you want it to *behave* like a chicken, make it a chicken. **If you want both** make your *own* "chickdog" and stop trying to make a dog a chicken or a chicken a dog. In short, write **your own class** to do the **specific** things you want, and **don't force** the builtin **generic** classes to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a recursive OpenStruct, another alternative is to use [Mash](https://github.com/intridea/hashie#mash) from the [hashie](https://github.com/intridea/hashie) gem:

```
require 'hashie'

text = Hashie::Mash.new(text_hash)
p text.ftp.lastname #=> nil
```